# How do you declare a gcp rate_limit_options block in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, security-policy, google-cloud-armor

I'm trying to create a gcp cloud armor rate limiting "throttle" resource but i keep getting the error below.

```
Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 20, in resource "google_compute_security_policy" "throttle":
│  172:     rate_limit_options {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "rate_limit_options" are not expected here.
```

Here is what my resource block looks like;

```
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "throttle" {
  name    = "${var.environment_name}-throttle"
  description = "rate limits request based on throttle"

  rule {
    action = "throttle"
    preview = true
    priority = "1000"
    match {
      versioned_expr = "SRC_IPS_V1"
      config {
        src_ip_ranges = ["*"]
      }
    }
    rate_limit_options {
      conform_action = "allow"
      exceed_action = "deny(429)"
      enforce_on_key = "ALL"
      rate_limit_threshold {
        count = "200"
        interval_sec = "300"
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

here is what my provide block look like

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project = var.project[var.environment_name]
  region  = "us-central1"
}
```

How do i declare the rate_limit_option block?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. Which provider are you using ("google" or "google-beta")? Use the **google-beta** provider. **Edit** your question to provide that information

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the swift response! I've modified my provider to "google-beta" and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Please update your question to show the provider. Details matter to solve problems. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For anyone looking at this issue, the `rate_limit_option` was added on [v4.10.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google-beta/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4100-february-7-2022) of google-beta provider

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "throttle" {
  name    = ${var.environment_name}-throttle"
  description = "rate limits"
  provider = google-beta

  rule {
    action = "throttle"
    preview = true
    priority = "1000"
    rate_limit_options {
      conform_action = "allow"
      exceed_action = "deny(429)"
      enforce_on_key = "ALL"
      rate_limit_threshold {
        count = "200"
        interval_sec = "300"
      }
    }
    match {
      versioned_expr = "SRC_IPS_V1"
      config {
        src_ip_ranges = ["*"]
      }
    }
 
  }
}
```

Comment: You are just showing HCL with no explanation. The only difference I see is you specified the provider. I provided that solution two months ago. Edit your question to clearly state what was the problem and why your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

The block **rate_limit_options** is supported by the **google-beta** provider.

Use this:

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project     = "my-project-id"
  ...
}
```

[Using the google-beta provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions#using-the-google-beta-provider)

Comment: I have my provider set as "google-beta" but its still failing with the same error.